# Python and Pandas: copying values from non NaN cells to Nan Cells if key values match

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and Pandas and I encountered this issue.

so, if I have 4 columns and some rows

| A. | B. | C. | D. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q50. | 12. | 34 | xy |
| Q50. | 23. | NaN. | NaN |
| Q52. | 01. | 50. | CAT |

I want if A is matching (Q50 in row 1 and row 2) to copy all values from row 1 to row 2 (in this example) values to the NaN.

so I will have:

| A. | B. | C. | D. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q50. | 12. | 34 | xy |
| Q50. | 23. | 34 | xy |
| Q52. | 01. | 50. | CAT |

I'm wondering if there is a way to use np.where()
where I can say if column A's value exists in my dataframe (row 2 where I have NaNs and row 1 where all cells are filled)
then set all NaN in row 2 to equal row 1.

EDIT ----- based on a request:

when I run df.head().to_dict()

{'A': {0: Q50',
1: 'Q52'
2: 'Q50'},
'B': {0: '12',
1: '01',
2: '23'},
'C': {0:'34',
1: '50',
2: 'NaN'}
'D': {0: 'xy',
1: 'CAT',
2: 'NaN'}}

Comment: `df.groupby` & [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html). Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Show what you have tried so far (code) in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby('A.').apply(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

or

```
df.groupby(df['A.'].values).ffill()
```

output:

```
     A.    B.    C.   D.
0  Q50.  12.0  34.0   xy
1  Q50.  23.0  34.0   xy
2  Q52.   1.0  50.0  CAT
```

*NB. you can't do `df.groupby('A.').ffill()` directly as this loses the column 'A.'*

Comment: I tries this solution, but its not working. when doing: df = df.groupby(df['A.').values).ffill(), it return a dataframe where all columns except A and B are NaN

Comment: @MFaragal how is it not working? please provide the samples you tested, how it failed, and eventually the error traceback if any

Comment: when I tried this line df.groupby('A.').apply(lambda x: x.ffill()) it gave me a (str ibject has no attribute 'ffill'

Comment: please edit the question to provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`